# why bindCallback is not a function?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Hi I am using this rxjs libraray .I am getting this error 
Rx.Observable.bindCallback is not a function

here is my code
http://jsbin.com/tuxucotake/edit?html,js,console,output

I am reading doc from here 
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

```
var getJSONAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(jQuery.getJSON);
var result = getJSONAsObservable('http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json');
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: @angular2 used rxjs thatwhy

Comment: Angular2 uses RXJS 5.

Comment: could you please share rxjs 5 link or update my jsbin or plunker

Comment: I think rxjs 5 is in beta phase

Comment: I don't know about Angular2 with JS (only TS and Dart). Angular2 still does use RXJS5 and I'm pretty sure it's not compatible with RXJS4

Comment: ok idea thanks I got the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using RXJS 4 but the docs you have linked to are RXJS 5

Comment: What has replaced `Observable.bindCallback()` in rxjs6?

Comment: https://medium.com/@cpyle/rxjs-functions-part-1-3275c1cdde21 and https://medium.com/@cpyle/rxjs-functions-part-2-63f06f018fa6 might help. I never used that function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer) answer, `bindCallback()` is not anymore part of `Observable`so the correct usage for current version of RxJs (6) would be:

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fenuqaqujo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
var getJSONAsObservable = rxjs.bindCallback(jQuery.getJSON);
var result = getJSONAsObservable('https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data? list=englishmonarchs&format=json');
result.subscribe(
  ([data,textStatus,jqXhr]) => console.log(data), 
  e => console.error(e));
```

Respectively for node:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs')
const {bindCallback} = Rx;
var getJSONAsObservable = bindCallback(jQuery.getJSON);
....
```